# Building a Python Dataframe column by stacking multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 objects, an empty dataframe, and a container dataframe to hold 10 rows and 1 column worth of data.. I want to build a dataframe by stacking the values of the container to the empty dataframe **in a single column**, but my attempts at doing so using append is resulting in a 2D matrix with NaN values..

NOTE: I could also use lists instead of dataframes, I just want to build a single column of data by stacking from scratch.

Code:

```
for x in range(2):
d_t=pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(df_1d.loc[[x]]))
A_count_css=A_count_css.append(d_t)
```

Here is the result of 2 iterations of the loop

[image: The result should be a single column]

The result should be a single column of data.

Comment: try to use pd.concat : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: I tried it, it gives the same result..

Comment: Have you tried renaming the columns so they all match?

Comment: Trying to rename column 1 to column 0 with in place =true makes the dataframe into a none type object.

Comment: Please provide input data and expected output as code and avoid images.